# How can I reach Prague airport during the night hours?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, taxis, prague, prg

I have a flight at 06:00 in the morning from Prague, which means I need to be at the airport around 04:00 in the morning.

How can I reach the airport from the center of the city?

Is taxi a good option? I heard is very cheap.. like 15 euros.. is this correct?

Answer (score 12):

### Public Transportation

The [public transportation](http://www.prg.aero/en/parking-transport/transport/public-transit/) web page of Vaclav Havel Airport mentions various forms of transportation, some of which seem to operate only during day-time. However, according to the DPP web page, [bus 510](http://www.dpp.cz/en/night-operation/) operates at night-time from 00:15 to 05:00:

> Na Beránku – I. P. Pavlova – Letiště (Prague Airport), bus 510
>
> - interval: 30 minutes
> - travel time: from I. P. Pavlova 45 minutes, total travel time 73 minutes
> - fare: per PIT tariff,
>
>   - ticket on the 75 minute: 32 CZK
>   - all-day tiket (24 hours): 110 CZK
>   - three-day ticket (72 hours): 310 CZK

Since the bus runs every 30 minutes, and the average journey time is 45 minutes, you could catch the 03:00 bus, at the latest, to arrive at 04:00 to the airport. This of course depends on where your actually start your journey.

### Taxi

You could also book a taxi in advance. Once again, the [Vaclav Havel web page on the matter](http://www.prg.aero/en/parking-transport/transport/official-taxi/) comes in handy. Having done this in July 2015 I ended up spending 300`CZK` (including tip) from Wenceslas Square to the airport at 04:00. My cab was prebooked and not hailed from the street. These prices are likely to become outdated very soon however so I suggest you call the cab company and ask for a quote.

Comment: Thanks, I believe taxis are around 15 euros for a trip to the airport from the center... if someone else could confirm..

Comment: @Patrick if you hail a cab on the street it should be around 20EUR. If you call a cab (here's a taxi company I [recommend](http://www.nejlevnejsi-taxi.cz/)), the fare should be around 12EUR.

Comment: @JonathanReez I used the company you recommended in July 2015. Everything went smooth and the price was reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

### Navigating public transportation

To get to [bus 510](http://www.dpp.cz/en/night-operation/) mentioned by `JoErNanO` above, you can ride the highly developed night tram network. Use the [Jizdnirady](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/pid/spojeni/) website to find full directions from your hotel:

[image: airport night directions]

### Ordering a cab

While in previous years it was sometimes necessary to preorder a cab by phone, you can now use one of the taxi apps to get a fair price without prebooking:

1. [Uber](https://www.uber.com/invite/mmddi) is the global taxi app. It was the cheapest app in Prague up until 2018, but currently they're the pricier option.
2. [Liftago](https://www.liftago.com/invite/MICHAL1586) is a local taxi app, with cheaper prices than Uber as of 2019.
3. If taxi apps are not your cup of tea, you can always use [Nejlevnejsi Taxi](http://www.nejlevnejsi-taxi.cz/) to make a booking by phone. They're the cheapest "offline" taxi company in Prague and don't overcharge tourists.

You get a 300 CZK bonus as a first-time Liftago customer and a 200 CZK bonus for Uber.

> NB: I am not affiliated with any taxi companies, all of the above is written from my personal experience